# I want to set a popup message when I close any file in windows, how is it possible?

Tags: scripting, popup, message, display

I am using virtual system and any changes in any file will be reverted after restart. I want to set a popup message that tell me to commit the changes in file before closing, how can I set it in windows?
I doesn't know more about windows programming / scripting.
Any body help greatly appreciated.

Regards,

no output yet and expecting good response.